# How to extend the java HashSet class with a new function?

Tags: java, android, hashset

I'm making an android app. I would like to extend the HashSet class and add to it a new function that picks a random element from the set. Everything else should behave as the normal HashSet.

So I thought of having this class:

```
public class RandomHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {
    private Random mRand = new Random();

}
```

And I want to add to it a function that performs this code on the HashSet:

```
if (set.size() == 0) {
    return null; 
}
int index = mRand.nextInt(set.size());
Iterator<Object> iter = set.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    iter.next();
}
return iter.next();
```

However, I'm not sure how to implement this function within the class, specifically how to call the instantiated set and how to iterate it.

In [HashSet source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/ojluni/src/main/java/java/util/HashSet.java) I see that they init a variable called 'map':

```
map = new HashMap<>();
```

For example, the HashSet add() function is implemented like this:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Can I also use 'map' in my function somehow (being private)?

Comment: The map field is private, so you won't have access to it

Comment: You have access to the sets iterator and size methods, so extending `HashSet` and adding this method should be simple, just remove `set.`

Comment: Don't extend HashSet, as this means you can only call this method on that specific class. You can create a method (maybe static) which simply takes any set and returns a random element; it doesn't have to be "baked into" the instance.

Comment: Agree with Andy, since this implementation would work with any `Collection`.

Comment: I know this is Java, but a good use case for Kotlin extension functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {
    private Random mRand = new Random();

    public E randomElement() {
        if (size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        int index = mRand.nextInt(size());
        Iterator<E> iter = iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            iter.next();
        }
        return iter.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work well! 
However, other comments suggest that I shouldn't extend HashSet at all, but instead implement a static method. So I'm having a second thought about it...

Comment: I don't see any problem with extend HashSet. It only depends how you use your class; Set<String> set1 = new RandomHashSet<>(); you only used method from Set; or HashSet<String> set2 = new RandomHashSet<>(); this is classic HashSet; or as our new RandomHashSet<String> set3 = new RandomHashSet<>();

Comment: This is a better approach then wrapping the HashSet in another class that "HAS A" HashSet because you could this pass this class around to other classes that need a HashSet.  BTW, The randomElement() function is O(n) time, versus if had an array O(1).